# using QTime and Qtimer as clock in Qlabel lead to heavy cpu usage

Tags: qt, qtimer, cpu-load, qtime

I have Problem when i activate `QTimer` To Show A clock inside a `Qlabel`, my small software will use around 25 to 40 % of CPU Power (I3 4160) so how to solve it to take less hardware resources?

```
QTimer *timer1 = new QTimer(this);
     connect(timer1,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(showtime()));
     timer1->start();
```

and this is my showtime() function

```
void Findlistrecord::showtime(){
    QTime time = QTime::currentTime();
    QString time_totext = time.toString("hh : mm : ss");
    ui->timelabel->setText(time_totext);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I see you didn't set an interval for you timer, so your timer will trigger as soon as it can. If you want to show the time with seconds accuracy I recommend that to use interval of 1000ms to reduce the process overhead.

```
timer1->start(1000);
```

Comment: now it doesn't use cpu at all :D wow great help from you bro <3 thank you really thank you